# Facing an issue when running .py script in windows used for zap testing which works on ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, proxy, zap

I have written .py script to run zap test on my ubuntu machine and now I am trying to run it on windows and facing an error "maximum retries reached" related to the connection,I have configured the zap proxy to live on localhost:8090, Below is my script I referen to the official documentation for help;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime
import os
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from pprint import pprint
from zapv2 import ZAPv2 
from zapv2 import ZAPv2 as ZAP
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import 
Options as FirefoxOptions

# The URL of the application to be tested
target = 'http://localhost:5074/hello'

apiKey = '1irjjncg7itnjut55dfgd2bc33'

firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.headless = True

# By default ZAP API client will connect to 
port 8080
# zap = ZAPv2(apikey=apiKey)
# Use the line below if ZAP is not listening on 
port 8080, for example, if listening on port 
8090
zap = ZAPv2(apikey=apiKey, proxies={'http': 
'http://127.0.0.1:8090', 'https': 
'http://127.0.0.1:8090'})

print('Spidering target {}'.format(target))
# The scan returns a scan id to support concurrent 
scanning
scanID = zap.spider.scan(target)
while int(zap.spider.status(scanID)) < 100:
# Poll the status until it completes
print('Spider progress %: 
{}'.format(zap.spider.status(scanID)))
time.sleep(1)

 print('Spider has completed!')
# Prints the URLs the spider has crawled
print('\n'.join(map(str, 
zap.spider.results(scanID))))
# If required post process the spider results


print('Ajax Spider target {}'.format(target))
scanID = zap.ajaxSpider.scan(target)

timeout = time.time() + 60*2   # 2 minutes from now
# Loop until the ajax spider has finished or the 
timeout has exceeded
while zap.ajaxSpider.status == 'running':
if time.time() > timeout:
    break
print('Ajax Spider status' + 
zap.ajaxSpider.status)
time.sleep(2)

print('Ajax Spider completed')
ajaxResults = zap.ajaxSpider.results(start=0, 
count=10)


# TODO: Start scanning the application to find 
vulnerabilities
print('Active Scanning target {}'.format(target))
scanID = zap.ascan.scan(target)
while int(zap.ascan.status(scanID)) < 100:
# Loop until the scanner has finished
print('Scan progress %: 
{}'.format(zap.ascan.status(scanID)))
time.sleep(25)

print('Active Scan completed')
# Print vulnerabilities found by the scanning
print('Hosts: {}'.format(', 
'.join(zap.core.hosts)))
print('Alerts: ')
pprint(zap.core.alerts(baseurl=target))

###########
alerts = zap.core.alerts(baseurl=target)
print('Alerts: ')
pprint(alerts)
```

And I am facing this issue;

```
device or resource(www.zaproxy.org) is not set 
up to accept connections on port "https"
```

Whats the difference between running the zap tests in Windows os and Ubuntu?

Comment: Debugging is always easier using the ZAP desktop GUI - have you tried that?
If you are automating ZAP then you may find the Automation Framework easier: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/automation-framework/